# How could i use r to add data to a table?

Tags: r, forecasting, tables, database, crostons-method

I am looking for an approach.

We have a historical table with the consumption per week of a list of items (19.000 item).

We want to predict the consumption for the next n weeks.

We are thinking on use R to do that prediction.

Our prediction expert recomend to use R, by using croston function from the forecast package.

I want to create a script to execute the prediction on each item and save the prediction on a table of mysql.

How could i do this? Could any one help me on the approach?

Regards

Comment: Is this more programming related question? Then its place should be in Stackoverflow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a lot more programming related question than question about statistical methods.

You can use RODBC library to connect your R session with MySQL dbms.

Is your R in the same machine as dbms? Do you have an system ODBC DSN defined?

Steps:

1) First R session gets data into data.frame in memory by executing SQL query.
2) Next your prediction algorithm loops this data N times.
3) Each loop writes a set of rows into a temporary table inside MySQL dbms.
4) When loop is finished, you can use R to write rows from the temp table into a production table via SQL.
5) Your predictions are ready to be used in other processes.